# Python if and elif not working, giving error

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I'm new in Python and doing an online tutorial. I have an assignment that I can not accomplish. My problem is that when I run this code, the `minimum` variable stays the same to `None` and does not record the new value input.

```
maximum = None
minimum = None
while True:
    try:
        num2 = raw_input('Type here ')
        if num2 == 'done':break
        else:
            num = int(num2)
            if num <= minimum:
                minimum = num
                print minimum
            elif num >= maximum:
                maximum = num
                print maximum


    except:
        print 'Invalid Entry'


print 'Maximum is %d' % maximum
print 'Minimum is %d' % minimum
```

Comment: Fix your formatting.

Comment: Have you tried [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) at all? First off, throw in some `print` statements to see what the values of each variable are at various points - you'll understand a little better then what's going on.

Comment: Additionally, if you're new to Python, we **strongly** suggest learning Python 3 first.

Comment: hi Matt! Thanks for the reply, i'm using learning python the hard way and coursera, and they both advised me to use python 2  rather then 3 also they advise me not to use any cool interpreter like pycharm and other, but to use maximum notepad++

Comment: @PIMg021 [LPTHW is awful](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). *Please* don't use it. *Do* use PyCharm if it'll help you learn. I can go on for a long time about the benefits of Py3 over Py2, but trust me when I say don't listen to LPTHW *or* Coursera. Python 2 is the past, Py3 is the present and future of the language. Nearly all open-source Python projects now use Python 3, many exclusively and others as a supported option. You'll learn a lot of bad habits (like trying to compare ints to None) in Py2 that aren't in Py3. Learn Py3 now, then go back to Py2 when you're proficient.

Comment: If you'd like to find a different tutorial, read [here](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) for some suggestions.

Comment: thanks Matt! i will check it our right away! cheers

Comment: Smart coder use `try: / except :` @PIMg021 Exception will guide you(not all time)

Comment: Debugging step 1: Remove `try ... except`. Debugging complete.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your are checking if `(some number) <= None` You cannot compare numbers with `None`. Instead, `minimum=float("inf")` and `maximum=float("-inf")` would set minimum to infinity, and maximum to negative infinity. That way, the first number entered would be less than infinity, setting it to `minimum`, and greater than negative infinity (setting it to `maximum`). Note that `elif maximum >= num` would need to be changed to `if maximum >= num` (to handle the first entered number).

Comment: I tried to put 0 and 0 on minimum, however how can the user place a nubmber smaller of 0? so i still have that issue, what i am tring to do is to catch the smallest and the biggest of the entry from the user.

Comment: No problem, although I have a tip for you: whenever you write an if/else statement, check the types of variables. If you are trying to compare numbers and `None`, just like comparing apples and oranges, you can't (unless you have no apples or oranges).

Comment: rather that cero, I would said infinite like this: `minimum=float("inf")` and `maximum=float("-inf")`

Comment: Actually, in Python 2 it *is* possible to compare integers (and floats) to `None`. Open an interpreter and try it. This is one of many reasons why we recommend new learners use Python 3 - it doesn't have this nonsensical behavior.

Comment: That's a good idea, but then `elif num >= maximum:` would have to be changed to `if num >= maximum` (to get the first number entered).

Comment: @Copperfield I think you have those backwards.

Comment: @MattDMo no if the idea is to get the max or min of the entered number, setting `minimum` to `inf` guaranty that in the first comparison `num` will be smaller and therefore change `minimum` to `num`, the same with `maximum`

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
maximum = None
minimum = sys.maxsize
while True:
    try:
        num2 = raw_input('Type here ')
        if num2 == 'done':break
        else:
            num = int(num2)
            minimum = min(minimum, num)
            maximum = max(maximum, num)
    except:
        print 'Invalid Entry'


if maximum is None:
    minimum = None

print 'Maximum is %d' % maximum
print 'Minimum is %d' % minimum
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `None` and `int`, Python does not know how to do that.
Instead, you should do:

```
maximum = float('-inf')
minimum = float('inf')
```

Any `int` would be greater than `-infinity` and lower than `infinity`, so things will work fine. Same thing can not be said about zeroes, so don't use those.

Also, look up `min` and `max` [builtins](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

Comment: As I mentioned below, Python 2 *does* compare integers and floats to None without errors. Just try it. The results don't necessarily make sense, but it doesn't error like it does in Python 3.

Comment: That's confusing. Well, I suppose relying on that behaviour is not a good habit to pick up.